# TPS Based Shell Script

Tags: shell-script

I am writing a shell script to test my soap web service's load handling. But I am not sure how to simulate the TPS value. Can you help me to find a way to handle that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you looked into [SoapUI](http://www.soapui.org/About-SoapUI/what-is-soapui.html) instead of writing your own load testing routine?

Comment: +1, there are the tutorials: http://www.soapui.org/Data-Driven-Testing/tutorials.html